# How do I reallocate memory to a pointer inside a struct?

Tags: c

I need to allocate memory to a pointer inside a struct but I can't figure out how to allocate memory to the pointer inside the `struct Compra`

```
struct Compra
{
    int id_cliente;
    float preco_final;
    int *id_artigos;
    int *conta_artigos;
    int receita;
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
};

void Alloc_Memoria_Pointers(struct Compra **compras, struct Contador **contadores, int incr)
{ 
    int *temp_a = NULL;
    int *temp_q = NULL;
    temp_a = (int*) realloc(*compras[0]->id_artigos, incr * sizeof(int));

    if(temp_a == NULL)
    {
        printf("Alocacao de memoria para id artigos falhada:(\n");
    }
    else
    {
        (*compras)[0].id_artigos = temp_a;
    }
}
```

Comment: `*compras[0]->id_artigos` or `(*compras)[0].id_artigos`? Both can't be correct.

Comment: i know i was just trying to figure it out which way it works, how can i send a pointer inside a struct to a function and then allocate the memory to that pointer inside the function?

Comment: Now what *is* `compras`? How do you call this function? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: And `*compras[0]->id_artigos` is definitely wrong (it's equal to `compras[0]->id_artigos[0]`)

Comment: If you're changing the contents of a field inside the struct, just pass a pointer to the struct (i.e. `struct Compra *compras` is enough). The only reason why you would need to pass `struct Compra ** compras` is if you had to replace the entire struct with a different instance. In most cases, you don't need a "pointer to a pointer".

Comment: I  want to allocate memory the sizeof(int) to the pointer *id_artigos inside the struct compras, i trying to send to fucntion (*compras)[0].id_artigos but the allocating failed i just cant figure out to allocate the memory of size int to the pointer inside the struct

Comment: Adding to this, don't cast realloc, just include stdlib.h

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, if you just want to modify (reallocate) a member of the structure, you only need to pass a pointer to the structure itself, not a pointer to a pointer to a structure.

Something like

```
struct Compra compra = { 0 };  // Initialize all member to "zero" or "null"
size_t new_size_of_artigos = 10;  // Example size

Alloc_Memoria_Pointers(&compra, new_size_of_artigos);
```

Then your function could be as simple as

```
void Alloc_Memoria_Pointers(struct Compra *compra, size_t new_size)
{
    int *temp_a = NULL;

    // Reallocate (or allocate) the memory
    temp_a = realloc(compra->id_artigos, new_size * sizeof *temp_a);

    if (temp_a == NULL)
    {
        printf("Alocacao de memoria para id artigos falhada:(\n");
    }
    else
    {
        compra->id_artigos = temp_a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
void Alloc_Memoria_Pointers(struct Compra **compras, struct Contador **contadores, int incr)
{
    struct Compra *local_ptr = *compras; //copy to a local pointer

    int *temp_a = NULL;
    temp_a = (int*)realloc(local_ptr->id_artigos, incr * sizeof(int));

    if (temp_a == NULL)
    {
        printf("Alocacao de memoria para id artigos falhada:(\n");
    }
    else
    {
        local_ptr->id_artigos = temp_a;
        printf("allocated");
    }
}
```

But you need to pass the address of a pointer,

```
struct Compra *l1_ptr ;
Alloc_Memoria_Pointers(&l1_ptr,10);
```